# How do I true Kinetix Pro wheels?

Tags: wheels

I have a pair of Kinetix Pro wheels on my Dahon folder. The front wheel has developed a wobble, so I got out my spoke key to fix it and.... there are no spoke nipples next to the rim. (The slight bulge you can see in the picture is due to the butting of the spoke, it's not a spoke nipple).

[image: Kinetix Pro wheel]

Presumably it's possible to true them from the inside of the rim, but if possible I'd rather not rip off the rim tape only to find out that I don't have the right tool - so if anyone knows what I need, I would be very grateful.

Comment: There are nipples somewhere -- either inside the rim or at the hub.  But it should be noted that a "sparse" spoke arrangement such as you have there is more sensitive to having the rim knocked askew to the point that it cannot be trued.

Comment: My guess is Park Tool SW-15, but I don't know if thats the right one. Maybe take the wheel to your local shop and see if they can match it to a tool. Then, buy the tool from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wheel uses internal (inverted) spoke nipples.

You need to take off the tire and tape and true from inside the rim, as in the picture below:

[image]

(Source: [Park Tool SW-15](http://www.parktool.com/product/3-way-internal-nipple-wrench-sw-15?category=Wheel%20%26%20Spoke) documentation)

The tool will be something like Park Tool SW-15/16/17/18/19. You'll need to look up what the particular right tool is for this job -- I don't know which one is the correct tool.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the Park Tool SW-15 is indeed suitable, specifially the 3.2mm square drive